# How do I find the probability distribution of a dependent variable given the probability distributions of its independent variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, physics

I have two probability distribution functions, $F$ and $G$, describing quantities $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Both $x$ and $y$ are required to find quantity $z$ - let's say $z = x^2(1-\cos(y))$.

$x$ is defined over a range which we can call [x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>], while y is defined over [0,2π]. Both are continuous.

Given that I have $F$ and $G$, how can I find the probability distribution for $z$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the domains of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: It sounds like you have two random variables $X, Y$ and you define a new random variable $Z$ that is a function of $X,Y$, say $Z=f(X,Y)$.  To find the distribution of $Z$ you need the _joint CDF_ $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. It is generally impossible to find the distribution of $Z$ with only the _marginal CDFs_ $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$.  In the special case when $X, Y$ are independent then the joint CDF is the product of marginal CDFs.

Comment: @callculus *x* is defined continuously over a range which I guess we can call [x1, x2], while y is defined over [0,2π].

Comment: @Michael We're in luck - X and Y are independent!

Comment: @TempUserPerson Please add all information to the question. Information in the comments can be read over easily.

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting please.

Comment: I see you didn't add the independence assumption in the edits.  You are using the well-known and well-used false theorem that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables for a problem, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.